# Translating a "PrintInfo-method" from python to Java

Tags: python, java, oop, methods, format

I am working on learning myself how to code in Java on the basis of knowing python fairly well.

For the sake of learning, I'm am "translating" an old python Class "bankAccount" from python to Java. So far this is going quite OK, but I'm having trouble with a method that prints out information on the bankAccount object.

The printout method i am trying to translate from python to java is:

```
    def print_info(self):
        first = self._first_name
        last = self._last_name
        number = self._number
        balance = self._balance

        s = f"{first} {last}, {number}, balance: {balance}"

        print(s)
```

This is what I have written in Java:

```
    public void printInfo() {
        String first = this.firstName;
        String last = this.lastName;
        double balance = this.balance;
        String s;

        s = String.format("\n%$1s %$2s %$f", first, last, "Balance: ", balance);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

The error message I'm getting is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '$'
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter.checkText(Formatter.java:2732)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2718)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2655)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2609)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.format(String.java:2897)
    at trix.uke1.BankAccount.printInfo(BankAccount.java:47)
    at trix.uke1.BankAccount.main(BankAccount.java:58)
```

I know how to get it working by typing:

```
System.out.println(this.firstName +" " + this.lastName + " " + "Balance: " + this.balance);
```

.. but I would like to be more fluent in using the String.format() function since I am very used to using f-strings in python.

Is there anyone who can help me solve this?
All help is welcomed and appreciated

Comment: I think the % and $ might be in wrong order: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is just a syntax issue:

For instance:

```
String firstName = "Richard";
String lastName = "Yu";
double balance = 1E40;
    
String s = String.format("\n%1$s %2$s Balance: %3$f", firstName, lastName,balance);
System.out.println(s);
```

Output:

```
Richard Yu Balance: 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
```

Comment: Perfect! That solved the problem! By the way. Is String.format() the closest thing to python f-strings? or is there other features in java that resemble the f-string even more?

Comment: Also: How do you use the format specifier to round up the number of decimals?

Comment: @fredericoamigo As far as I know String.format() is the closest (in the sense that you won’t get away from passing arguments in without a custom method or something).

Comment: If you want to round I would recommend doing it before you pass in as argument or using %.nf where n is the number of decimal places you want to round to. But I would refer more to docs for your specific needs.